# Can't install Ubuntu on my Windows 7 laptop

Tags: wubi, windows-7

I tried installing Ubuntu in two different ways:

First, I tried the Windows Installer, and it goes well until I reboot the system and, when booting on Ubuntu, I get the error:

> No root file system defined.

Second, I uninstalled wubi by going to to Control Panel -> Uninstall Programs -> Ubuntu. Then, I booted the laptop from the live CD and selected install. It boots okay but in the screen right after the one that says to make sure you have 4.5 GB available, Internet connection, etc, when I click continue it throws me a message saying that Ubuntu had an internal error and asks me if I want to report the error. After that, I just have a black screen and nothing else! No Ubuntu installed, no boot option to go back to Windows. Nothing!

My goal is to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 (without the hassle of formatting the computer, creating partition, etc). How can I do it (preferable using Windows Installer)? How can I solve the "No root file system defined" that I encountered when I used the Windows Installer?

Comment: The same problem I have

Comment: There must be bug in grub bootloader

Comment: What release of Ubuntu? Try to boot to a live desktop (boot from the live CD and select "Try Ubuntu") then connect to the internet and run the http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and pastebin that.

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info), this will give us valuable information to help you.

Answer (score -1):

I once tried to instal through wubi but for me its easier partitioning. Esentially, when installing ubuntu you want to have three partitions. One for ubuntu "/" one for "efi boot" and one for "swap". Swap only needs to be as much as your RAM (typically). For the boot partition only 50mb and ubuntu partition depends how big you want it to be...i hope I helped at least a bit in explaining partitionong even though you need advice on wubi.

Comment: User also mentioned that installing with the live CD didn't work.